# get twitter user info

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit

I am using Sharekit for Twitter and Facebook integration. After authentication I am getting use did, screen name and keys. Now I also need to fetch user info like image, name etc. But didn't find any way to fetch user info. I am using [this API](http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=), but it is not working.

How can I get the API working so that I can fetch the required information?

Comment: if you can't get it by using sharekit. And if you dont mind using other library. then try FHSTwitterEngine it will give u these data.

Answer (score 0):

why using Share Kit ,  Use Twitter Api V1.1 to Fetch Complete User Info
check below Links ...

http://questiontrack.com/how-to-get-user-details-using-twitter-api-v1.1-twitter-error-215-1073076.html

Hope its HelpFull..